# Como filtrar datos de Firebase por varios hijos

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en Android en la cual necesito listar universidades segun las carreras que ofrecen.
Guardo mis datos en Firebase de la siguiente manera.
[image: orden de datos en Firebase]

para filtrar por nombre me funciono esto.

```
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
            child("Universidades").orderByChild("nombre").equalTo("UAP");
```

intente esto para filtrar por carreras pero me me sale error ya que no se puede usar dos orderByChild.

```
Query ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                child("Universidades").orderByChild("carreras")orderByValue().equalTo("Sistemas");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te dice el error, no es posible hacer una query con dos orderBy , para solucionar esto existen dos formas.

La primera es rearmar la estructura de tu base de datos tal que cada carrera este guardada bajo un key en una lookup table.

```
carreras {
pushIdCarrera : sistemas
pushIdCarrera: Ingenieria
pushIdCarrera: matematicas
}
```

Esto te va a permitir hacer la query a este nodo para saber que carreras tienes y vas a poder obtener el key de cada carrera para luego ubicarlo en la tabla principal.

La segunda opcion es recorrer toda la tabla, extraer todas las carreras con un for y hacer la pregunta del lado del cliente.

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  ...
          array.add(carrera);
                }
```

Luego de recorrerlo y guardar los datos en un array podes filtrar ese array del lado del cliente para preguntar.